# Permission for a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have two lists in my site and two group people. I want to set permission for group A can only access to list 1 and group B can only access to list 2. How can I do like that with share point foundation web part 2013? Do some one know about that? Please help me. Thanks so much !!

Comment: Can you break each list's permission, and assign the specific group to each list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are the steps for achieve Unique permission for List.

- Go to List Settings
- Click on "Permissions for this list"
- Click On "Stop Inheriting Permission" as shown below

[image]

- click On "Grant Permission"as shown below

[image]

- Give Your Group Permission on this list.
- If you already added both group in this list then just remove one of group after Unique permission.